Is the bitcoin still mine, available?
I purchased bitcoin 2x this week at $ $215.00 and $350.00. I put it in a wallet that I was instructed to by a “financial advisor”. I was told they ran it in trade on virtualfxtrade.uk I really think this was a scam. He said I made $8136 on the same day but is asking for $1600.00 fee for me to withdraw the $8136. If it is scam, do I still own the bitcoin? I have reciepts of purchase and wallet info.
How can I check?
